# Visual studio code extension debug in run time

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Short version I want to start debugging the current extension I am currently using to run some commands.

Long version we have a custom testing framework that wraps around js-mocha as CLI there are no issues we provide test definitions and Mocha takes care of the reporting and the execution of the tests.

Now we have an extensions that help creation of configuration that our framework is testing and we want to include the execution and debugging of said tests to the extension. Just the execution was easy get the test definition execute the test. Now the debugging part is ctricky since I would need to start debuggin the extension code itselfe. Because debugging the framework to see how the test progresses thrue the test steps is assential.

I already tried to call `process._debugProcess(PID)` which did not start debugging of the extension.

I am asking here if any one has any other ideas that I could try, I am thinking of trying to spawn a new process (run the CLI test framework) and start raising events which hopefully the extensions will be able to pick up.

I want to execute a test via the framework without mocha since I do not need the whole report just the result of the function that calls the test within the framework.

Comment: if it is an extension just create a launch config to debug extensions, see the extension doc

Comment: if that does not work add a lot of `console.log` to the extension, poor mans debugger

Comment: Hi @rioV8 for developing the extension yes we you the config to launch and debug the extension. What I am asking is when the extension is installad on VSCode to start debugging it when it is already in use

Comment: why not use it when you have launched it in the debugger, it is installed in the `[Extension Host]` version of VSC

Comment: @rioV8 I want to just debug a specific part of the code when the test is executed the nit should stop debugging. If it is always running in debug mode would not be ideal.

Comment: the debugger runs or it runs not, just open the workspace with the tests when you have the extension under debug, and only run 1 specific test

Comment: @rioV8 I understand that the idea of the extension is to be always running since users are using it to make configuration tests with it it is not just to run it in an instance here and there.